# How to get math mode curly braces in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, braces

The only curly braces in TikZ I'm currently aware of are the ones in the library `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}`. However, I don't like the way they look, I'd much prefer ordinary braces used in math mode.

I have no idea how to get them. Help is appreciated. Thank you in advance and God bless.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\begin{document}

This is ugly:

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt}] (0,0) -- (5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

This is pretty: \\
$\overbrace{\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

When trying to compile this code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,calligraphy}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw [very thick,decorate,decoration={calligraphic brace,amplitude=10pt}] (0,0) -- (5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I get the following [log file](https://pastebin.com/GekXnd2a) with errors (Pastebin link).

`pdflatex --version` gives this output:

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018/W32TeX)
kpathsea version 6.3.0
Copyright 2018 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.34; using libpng 1.6.34
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.00
```

Comment: `\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,calligraphy}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw [very thick,decorate,decoration={calligraphic
brace,amplitude=10pt}] (0,0) -- (5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: @marmot Thank you! The thing is, the compiler is giving me an error in `tikzlibrarycalligraphy.code.text` on line 707.

I also encourage you to post this as an answer so I can upvote and tick it after the issue is resolved. :)

Comment: Update your TeX installation. If you are using overleaf, quit.

Comment: @marmot I'm using TeX Live 2018 with TeXstudio, I think.

Comment: You could just post the very precise code you trying to compile, specify your TeX installation and post the exact version of the error message. I am sure this will be resolved then. Without this information I am less sure.

Comment: @marmot There, I posted a link to my whole log file in my post and added a more accurate description of my version of LaTeX (as given by `pdflatex --version`). Hope this helps!

Comment: @GregorPerčič as I see it's similar error https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/463282/undefined-control-sequence-g-prg-map-int

Comment: @DenysPotapov Thank you, the suggested fix worked! You can post this as an answer, so I can upvote and tick it.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372776/appealing-braces-in-tikz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use the `very thick` modifier. And if you have an older version of latex uncomment the fix:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

% uncommment next lines if you get "Undefined control sequence ..." error
% \usepackage{expl3}
% \ExplSyntaxOn
% \int_new:N \g__prg_map_int 
% \ExplSyntaxOff

\usetikzlibrary{decorations,calligraphy}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw [very thick,decorate,decoration={calligraphic brace,amplitude=10pt}] (0,0) -- (5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you have recent (less than about half year old)  installation of LaTeX, than this fix is not needed anymore. And, please extend your answer with complete code for this calligraphic brace :-).